# CusrsorAdapter extend two static class to hold two views

Tags: android, view, adapter, extends, android-cursor

I have cursor adapter which extends one static class with one View

```
public class CursorRecyclerViewAdapter extends CursorAdapter<CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.CursorHolder> {
    @Override
    public CursorHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(id, parent, false);
      return new CursorHolder(itemView, parent)
    }
}
static class CursorHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
}
static class CursorHolder2 extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
}
```

How can i return on onCreateViewHolder CursorHolder2 or CursorHolder?
Because I need to have two Views in this CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.

Can I somehow add to `CursorAdapter<CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.CursorHolder>`  additional `CursorRecyclerViewAdapter.CursorHolder2` ?

Comment: You need to use view type , see the example here - [Recycler view multiple view types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-types)

Answer (score 0):

In my case best solution is to use ConcatAdapter.